# How to upload an PDF file with cypress.io

Tags: cypress

I would like to upload a PDF file using cypress.
The idea will be to go and find the pdf file into my directory.
I didn't find some way yet.

This is the element used to upload

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a clear question being asked here. Also, it appears that your post is incomplete. Please edit to ask a clear question, and provide more context to your question, and maybe some code samples.

Answer (score 5):

**2022 Update**

Since Cypress [v9.3.0](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/releases/tag/v9.3.0) you can use

```
.selectFile('fileName.pdf')
```

you can find more details about it in [Cypress api docs](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/selectfile)

Answer (score 4):

Cypress doesn't support file upload out of the box. 
[cypress-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload) is a npm package which provides a custom cypress command to upload files easily.
*But, it requires the file to be present in the fixtures folder.*

Sample code for uploading pdf file:

```
const fileName = 'myfile.pdf';

cy.fixture(fileName).then(fileContent => {
  cy.get('#filesToUpload').upload({ fileContent, fileName, mimeType: 'application/pdf' }, { subjectType: 'input' });
});
```

You can also find more workarounds here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/170

Comment: Hello, Do you have an exemple on how to use it ?

Comment: Hello Bushra Alam,
Thanks for your help.
But my issue here is that I do not have an input on my file.
I have a button that open a chrome windows allowing me to seach on my desktop for the file I want to upload

Comment: Just made a test with your exemple. A pdf is uploaded.
But a blank PDF. It is normal ?

Comment: For new readers: Please note that the command `upload` in newer versions of `cypress-file-upload` has been deprecated and replaced with `attachFile`, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-file-upload#api

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @bushra you need to install the 'cypress-file-upload' package and then you can do this :)

```
Cypress.Commands.add("UploadFile", function () {
   cy.fixture("someFile", "binary")
    .then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob)
    .then((fileContent) => {
   cy.get('someElement').attachFile({
     fileContent,
     filePath: "someFile.pdf",
     fileName: "someFile.pdf",
  });

});
```