# Adding file to dropzone Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I am trying to add a pdf file to a dropzone in a Cypress test that Im creating
Ive added the `cypress-upload-file` package to help me do this.
In my commands.js file I have

```
Cypress.Commands.add("AddCandidate", function (candidate) {
cy.contains("Candidates").click()
cy.contains('Import Candidate').click()
cy.get('[id="resumeDz"]')
    .attachFile({ './resumes': 'example.pdf', encoding: 'utf-8', subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' });})
```

and in my test I have

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

describe('Add candidate', () => {
  before(function () {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env("home_page"));
    cy.fixture('user').then(function (user) {
      this.user = user
    cy.SignIn({ email: (this.user.email), password: (this.user.password) })
    })
  })

  it('Adds Candidate', function () {
    cy.AddCandidate({})
  })})
```

When running the test I get `"filePath" is not valid.
Please look into docs to find supported "filePath" values

Is there a specific way that i need to define the path ? Ive tried adding the full path, but Im still getting the same error. Is there something im missing ?`

SOLUTION

I ended up finding the solution.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("AddCandidate", function (candidate) {
cy.contains("Candidates").click()
cy.contains('Import Candidate').click()
cy.fixture('example.pdf', 'binary')
    .then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob)
    .then(fileContent => {

cy.get('[type="file"]').attachFile({
  fileContent,
  filePath: 'example.pdf',
  fileName: 'example.pdf',
});
cy.wait(1000)
cy.contains('Start').click()
cy.contains('Done').click()
});
```

})

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to `.attachFile()` are a little messed up

```js
cy.get('[id="resumeDz"]')
  .attachFile('./resumes/example.pdf', { 
    encoding: 'utf-8', 
    subjectType: 'drag-n-drop' 
   });
```

presuming `./resumes/example.pdf` is the path to the file relative to the fixtures folder.

Comment: For some reason the test is now uploading a blank pdf. Everything indicates that it was successful, but the pdf is blank. Does this maybe have something to do with the encoding ?@SteveZodiac

Comment: Take a look here [How to upload an PDF file with cypress.io](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57952376/4716245), there's an option `mimeType: 'application/pdf'`.

Comment: I tried this now, but its still the same. I see in the comments of that question someone else also said they are getting a blank pdf

Comment: If I console.log the input element, I can see the file in files property and it has a non-zero size. Will take a look further.

Answer (score 4):

With newer versions you can use the native cypress drag&drop action:

```
cy.get('#dropzone')
  .selectFile('cypress/fixtures/file.txt', { action: 'drag-drop' });
```