# Getting different error message when uploading file through cypress than manually

Tags: javascript, web, automated-tests, cypress, cypress-file-upload

I was writing end to end test case for a site. In this site, user is supposed to upload python file. I want to test what happens if I rename png file with `*.py* extension and upload it. When I did manually, the website gave the error

> ERROR: You have submitted a file factorial.py of type py but the contents are of image/png type

However, when I uploaded through cypress using `cypress-file-upload` plugin, it gave me following error:

> ERROR: You have submitted a file factorial.py of type py but the contents are of application/octet-stream type

Why is this so? Am I missing something or am getting diffrent message because of the way the plugin uploads file in some peculiar manner? Can I imitate the manual file upload output through cypress (that is get exactly the same error of `image/png type`)?

#### Update

I also checked for the mp3 file. Manual upload was giving error:

> ERROR: You have submitted a file factorial.py of type py but the contents are of audio/mpeg type

whereas cypress upload was giving same `application/octet-stream type`-error.

Also, my code to upload the file looks like this:

```
cy.get('input[name="docfile"]').attachFile(filePath)
cy.contains('input','Upload').click()
```

Explicitly adding a mimetype also doesn't work and still gives same error:

```
cy.get('input[name="docfile"]').attachFile({ filePath: _filePath, mimeType : _mimeType })
```

Comment: Can you add the code to how you are uploading the file ?

Comment: @ItsNotAndy Please find the code I have added at the bottom of the question.

Comment: You might want to specify the file you are trying to upload. Im not sure exactly what it would look like, but will do some research and post a answer in a bit. Have a look at this for now. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57925670/how-to-upload-an-pdf-file-with-cypress-io/69104009#69104009

Comment: I downloaded random image online and changed its file type to `*.py` and tried its upload. Also it didn't work by explicitly specifying mimetype as `cy.get('input[name="docfile"]').attachFile({ filePath: _filePath, mimeType : _mimeType })`.